# jquery Ready not trigger after ajax load (while useing .on() )

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, triggers

I'm making an ajax driven website, all pages are loaded via ajax into an div.

I need a way to check if a specific page is loaded. Too bad for me (in this case anyway) is that javascript is not excecuted. To overcome that problem I've placed an image `#testCase` in that page and tried to bind an load event to it. I can't get it to work.
I've got this atm:

```
$(document).on('load ready','#testCase', function(){
    alert('yeah');
});
```

But no alerts here. Every answer I find tells me to use `.on()`, which I clearly am. The image exists, the ID is correct, it's a unique image only existing in that page and I can see it has loaded.

Anyone who can tell me why my event isnt getting triggered?

---

Might be handy to know, the following code is right above the previous code, and does work:

```
$(document).on('change', '#QuickSelect', function(){
    alert( $(this).find('option:selected').val() );
})
```

Comment: I don't know why `load` event is not firing but you could use the `success` method of you ajax call.

Comment: No, because that would trigger each load. I only want 1 specific page (out of about 50) to perform this action. I dont want to hardcode some url, so thats not really an option either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be you problem: [on() additional notes](http://api.jquery.com/on/#additional-notes):

> In all browsers, the load, scroll, and error events (e.g., on an < img > element) do not bubble. In Internet Explorer 8 and lower, the paste and reset events do not bubble. Such events are not supported for use with delegation, but they can be used when the event handler is directly attached to the element generating the event.

And the `ready` event is for the `document` only.

Comment: Hm ok, I missed that. That explains why the event isnt triggered, but it isnt a solution to my original problem :)

Comment: The hover **does** work, so im going to use that to trigger other events :)